# How to change the 'sharing mode' of an already opened file, associated with a given FILE handle?

Tags: c++, windows

My MAIN "C++" Windows application processes a file opened by CreateFile, with 0x00000000 as sharing mode.
The application is the only writer to that file, from which others can optionally 'read only'.
The above setting disallows any access to the file by others.

At certain points in time this restrictive approach is a MUST.
Yet - there are many situation along time axis where FILE_SHARE_READ policy could have been temporarily used instead.

Is there a way for my application to switch dynamically between sharing modes while the file is open?
Having this option will allow my application to dynamically disallow access while it is busy in critical writes but allow read access while it is idle.

Re-opening the file over and over again is rather awkward and is not considered as a serious option.

Thanks.

Hillel.

Comment: I believe it can't be done with plain [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) but you might be able to workaround this with a device driver that managers this for you

Comment: You can't change the sharing mode on the fly, but you set the sharing mode to FILE_SHARE_READ and then use LockFile() when you need exclusive access.